# What is Zealot doing to the guests who barged into the house?

Tags: mother

In *Mother!* Zealot asks guests to pin their thoughts on the wall and he 
sticks ink on their face with his thumbs.

[image]

What is Zealot doing to the guests who barged into the house?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ash_Wednesday#/media/File:US_Navy_080206-N-7869M-057_Electronics_Technician_3rd_Class_Leila_Tardieu_receives_the_sacramental_ashes_during_an_Ash_Wednesday_celebration.jpg

Comment: Mark of the beast?